# How to find which indexes are read-only file group?

Tags: sql-server

How to find which indexes reside in `read-only filegroup`? I need this to exclude them when I try to `REORDER` or `REBUILD` them.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT i.name AS FileGroup FROM sys.filegroups d 
        JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.data_space_id = d.data_space_id 
        WHERE (d.is_read_only = 1) AND (i.name LIKE ' ... index name ... ')) 
    PRINT 'Do NOT REBUILD! File-Gruop is READ-ONLY';
```